# Comment/Uncomment code based on condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have been using the [gulp-remove-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-code) plugin to remove the specific code from the source files, when I need to change the environment from **staging** to **production** or vice-versa. Most of the changed code is API keys and boolean flags. This is for JS, Python, and Yaml files.

The problem with the approach is that, I need to keep the original file at a separate place, since it removes the other environment code.

Instead of removing the code based on a variable, I want to comment or uncomment code, so that I can do an in-place `gulp.dest()` without having a separate file.

Is there any way to do it via '`gulp`' or using the '`gulp-remove-code`' plugin or any other plugin?

Comment: Do you have absolutetly different behavior for different environments? Or just different variables?

Comment: @Lazyexpert Just different value for variables. Boolean flags, URLs, and API keys are the only things I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

I use npm module [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) for that purposes.

All you have to do is:

- set `NODE_ENV` env variable
- add config files with the same names as `NODE_ENV` variable
- set `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` env variable

This approach is very convenient.